# SQL Procedure to check if the transaction took place between time 23:30 to 6:30

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if the transaction took place between 23:30 of one day to 6:30 of next day.

I am using the following code.

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME
DECLARE @EndTime TIME
DECLARE @TrxnDateTime TIME
   select @TrxnDateTime= CONVERT(Varchar(15),Cast(dtTrxnDateTime as time))
   from tbl1 where iTransactionId = 1
SET @EndTime='6:00'
SET @StartTime='23:30'
SET @TrxnDateTime='3:30'


PRINT @StartTime
PRINT @EndTime
PRINT @TrxnDateTime

IF(@TrxnDateTime > @StartTime AND @TrxnDateTime < @EndTime)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Working'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Rule Not Tripped'
    END
```

How I can check if the transaction is between 23:30 of one day to 6:30 of the next day as my code above is not working?

Comment: How can you tell if something is previous day if you only have TIME part? Is dtTrxnDateTime a DATETIME column?

Comment: See Amit's answer. TIME datatype knows nothing about Date boundaries. It runs from 00:00:00.0000 to 23:59:59.xxx in SS and is an analog for the 24-hours of an indeterminate day. BTW SQL Server does not conform to ISO standard in that SS does not accept 24:00 as a valid representation for "midnight tonight" vs "00:00" for "midnight this morning". In SQL Server TIME corresponds to ALMOST the 24 hours of a day! The time of your transaction, extracted from the DateTime of the transaction, will EITHER be after 23:30 OR it will be before 06:30. A TIME value cannot be after 23:30 AND before 06:30.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: the terms "previous day" and "next day" are not what OP really means. They are meaningless, and indeed misleading, in the context of OP's code which involves the TIME datatype. I don't think you should have removed my proposed edit "between the hours". "one day" and "next day" are still problematic.

Comment: @Tim - perhaps, but the real crux of the solution is the OP will need to use the datetime type, not just time as the resolution would be to compare a value with a datetime from one day to a datetime from the next day to see if that datetime value being compared lies between the other two.

Comment: The idiomatic natural language (spoken English) way of phrasing this time concept: "The robbery took place between the hours of 11:30pm and 6am".  Between the hours of... But when using the TIME datatype in the calculations, as distinct from a DateTime type, the idiomatic natural language "between" does not correlate to the SQL `BETWEEN` operator.   `T > 11 and T < 6` will not resolve to true.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know something like "Did the transaction occur after bedtime snack and before breakfast". Amit's simple solution would work if that is indeed all the OP wants to know. The OP needs to clarify his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change `AND` WITH `OR` HERE...

```
IF(@TrxnDateTime > @StartTime OR @TrxnDateTime< @EndTime)
```

It is so because it not possible that both condtion can  become true togehere...looking at your request it shuld return true when any of your condtion become true..so use `OR` instead of `AND` .

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartTime Datetime
DECLARE @EndTime Datetime
DECLARE @TrxnDateTime Datetime
   select @TrxnDateTime= CONVERT(Varchar(15),Cast(dtTrxnDateTime as Datetime))  from tbl1 where iTransactionId = 1

-- I guess you are getting @TrxnDateTime from DB, so you dont need to set it

   SET @EndTime='2013-05-08 06:00:00.000'
   SET @StartTime='2013-05-07 23:30:00.000'



PRINT @StartTime
PRINT @EndTime
PRINT @TrxnDateTime

IF(@TrxnDateTime > @StartTime AND @TrxnDateTime< @EndTime)

   BEGIN
PRINT 'Working'
END
ELSE
   BEGIN
PRINT 'Rule Not Tripped'
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variable @TrxnDate created dynamically condition

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @TrxnDate DATE
SET @StartTime = '23:30:00'
SET @EndTime = '06:30:00'
SET @TrxnDate = '20130508'

IF EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM tbl1
           WHERE iTransactionId = 1
             AND dtTrxnDateTime > DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @TrxnDate) - 1, @StartTime)
             AND dtTrxnDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @TrxnDate) + 1, @EndTime)
           )
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Working'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Rule Not Tripped'
END
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5de5e/3)